# I want to set pagination using PREV and NEXT button using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, pagination

I want to set pagination with **Prev** and **Next** button at bottom of tableview and each page will display 100 records. How can I do this, Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

My web Request API is designed as follow:

```
/getRecorods?pageSize=100&pageNo=1
```

Comment: If I ignore my suspicion that this contravenes iOS design guidelines for tableviews, it's an interesting problem. My immediate thought is to use a tabbar, but you'll need  to manage/limit the 'numbered' items programmatically, depending on device, orientation, etc. This is important as iOS will override your intentions if there are more items than can be displayed on the tabbar - think about 12 items on an iPhone. You can add/remove tabbar items programmatically easily enough and then they can update the range of tableview rows being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just created global array called jsonArray and one int for pagesize constant of 100, and pageNo start with 1. 
When you tap next button just increment pageNo +=,and decrement pageNo -= if tapping previous button.The object you get from server, parse into jsonArray and reload tableview.

Thanks for your time.